# Calculus Books, preferably Soviet.

Tags: calculus, soft-question, book-recommendation

I would like some book recommendations on calculus books for novices. I love old Russian texts and if you you suggest such books(no issue if they are rigorous), I would be very grateful. If the text is quite challenging, I have no problem. But it should be interesting with proper exposition of topics.

The book should be good for self-study, preferably a textbook(again, for beginners). And it's not necessary for it to be Soviet. Just anything good. I merely like Soviet/Slavic books and so, the title.

Thanks to you all.

Edit again:Please try to abstain from suggesting analysis books. All I want is a nice, rigorous Book on Integral and Differential Calculus. Doesn't matter which origin(at this point), but should be translated into English. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you may actually want a book on "real analysis." There are several well known ones (you can Google it); I don't know about Russian ones in particular. I used a yellow book by Protter when I was in school.

Comment: I've read and enjoyed Kolmogorov and Fomin in English.  It's more advanced than calculus (metric spaces, topological spaces, etc.), and I have know idea how the original reads.  But check it out if you're interested.

Comment: Do you mean written in Russian or in English by a Russian author ?

Comment: If an intro to Integration and Differentiation are provided, why not.

Comment: The book may be written in Russian(translated to English) or by a Russian author, doesn't matter. Plus, please realise, I'm just in high school, but would like something extremely challenging and serious.

Comment: Vladimir Zorich, [Mathematical Analysis I & II (Springer, 2nd ed 2016)](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Analysis-Universitext-V-Zorich/dp/366248790X).

Comment: Not Russian but good nonetheless http://xn--webducation-dbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Introduction-to-differential-calculus-_-systematic-studies-with-engineering-applications-for-beginners-PDFDrive.com-.pdf

Comment: @Sen47 I am in same boat as you: I am self-studying mathematic. I recommend Calculus by James Stewart. Though it is not Russian, it is nonetheless a very popular book. You can find it at Open Library for online reading. Few months ago, I ordered a copy of "Calculus, Metric Version" by same author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A (possibly the) standard classic is:
Г. Фихтенгольц. Курс дифференциального и интегрального исчисления. (G. Fichtenholtz. The course of differential and integral calculus.)

I personally like very much the following two courses:

Л. Кудрявцев. Курс математического анализа (L. Kudryavtsev. Mathematical Analysis Course)
(there are several editions of, in fact, two related courses - a shorter one of two books, and a longer one of three books);

V. Zorich: Mathematical Analysis
(the best existing MA course in opinion of V. Arnold).

Comment: do you know where I can find G. Fichtenholtz. The course of differential and integral calculus?

Answer (score 5):

I would like to recommend "Problems in Mathematical Analysis Hardcover" – 1989
by Boris Demidovich (Editor), G. Yankovsky (Translator). This is a wonderful problem book which has lots of challenging problems. Another wonderful book is "Differential and integral calculus" by Grigorii Mikhailovich Fichtenholz.

Comment: Anything for theory building?

Comment: There are concepts, formulas, and theorems before problems in each chapter.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted.

Comment: @Sen47, see the update.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I checked out Demidovich and seem to like it. Will check the other one too.

Answer (score 5):

I'd  like to suggest 'Introductory real Analysis' and 'Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis ' both  by A.N.Kolmogorov

Comment: Sir, they seem to be too advanced for me...

Comment: What courses in mathematics you have ? The first one is pretty basic starts with set theory only . @Sen47

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the title and author's name. I have just borrowed a book online a few moments. :)

Answer (score 2):

By Grigorii Mikhailovich Fichtenholz there is also " TheFundamentals of Mathematical Analysis"

Answer (score 2):

L.V. Tarasov has written a book entitled **Calculus: Basic Concepts for High Schools**. Its first Russian edition was published in 1979 and its English translation in 1982.

This is not a recommendation. I mention the book here merely because it is the only Russian calculus textbook I know of. Someone has put the book on archive.org and its XeLaTeX source in a Gitlab repo, but I am not sure whether they are legal (hence no hyperlinks here).

Comment: Thanks, sir. I liked this book but right now I need something rigorous. Most probably, I'll be taking Fichtenholz's book. Thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: @Sen47 Go to this website called Open Library. There, you will find tons of books for online reading. Nearly all the math books are there. Some foreign books are there. Check out also Internet Archive.

Answer (score 2):

I like to recommend the both parts of the calculus books by Balmohan Limaye here is the link
https://g.co/kgs/iexgM8

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading the Chinese translation of Vladimir I. Smirnov's multi-volume "Course of Higher Mathematics" in the summer before freshman year, and liking its balance of rigor and richness. However, the English edition seems too expensive.
For a more rigorous treatment, Sergey M. Nikolsky's two-volume "Course in Mathematical Analysis" is hard to beat.

Answer (score 1):

The book Concepts, Problems and Solutions in School Calculus : A Dialogue Approach by Lev Tarasov and Chandra Shekhar Kumar ( ISBN-13 : 978-9354372926 ) can be a good starting point for beginners because it doesn't assume any previous knowledge on calculus.
[image]